# How to dynamically resize a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# user interface. I have created a window as shown in the first image. But if the user drag the window and make it bigger, I would like for it to make each `richTextBox` expand with it as shown in the second image. For example, make the `richTextBox4` bigger proportional to the size of the window. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Image1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `TableLayoutPanel` to your Form. Per default this panel has two columns and two rows.

Then you add one `TextBox` to each cell and set the `Dock`-Property of each `TextBox` to `Fill`.

The last step thing to do is either set the `Dock`-Property of your `TableLayoutPanel` to `Fill` or set the `Anchor`-Property of your `TableLayoutPanel` to `Left | Right | Bottom | Top`. Then your panel will be resized together with the Form.

All these steps can be done with the designer.

Answer (score 5):

Make use of `TableLayoutControl`. You can have one control per cell of that table. Now, on that table, you set:

```
Dock: Fill
Column Width: Percentage or absolute value as per needs
Row Height: Percentage or absolute value as per needs
```

On the controls, like textboxes in your case, set `Dock` to `Fill`.

Read about it and try. If you get stuck, do come back with questions.

Comment: If you set Dock:Fill for the TableLayoutControl, that button will be on top of it or under.

Comment: Not if button too is in a TableLayoutControl.

Answer (score 1):

The same result can be achieved by using TableLayoutControl with one text box in each cell
and then setting anchor property of each control (text boxes and TableLayout) to Left,Top, Right and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in designer.

Use the `TableLayoutPanel`, and set its Anchor property to `Top`,`Bottom`,`Left`,`Right` and for each RichtTextBox inside the cells set `Dock` to `Fill`.

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.richTextBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.richTextBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.richTextBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F)); //this line sets the Column percentage
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox4, 1, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox3, 0, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox2, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 80);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(861, 567);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 27);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 47);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // richTextBox1
        // 
        this.richTextBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
        this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(424, 277);
        this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
        // 
        // richTextBox2
        // 
        this.richTextBox2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.richTextBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(433, 3);
        this.richTextBox2.Name = "richTextBox2";
        this.richTextBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(425, 277);
        this.richTextBox2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.richTextBox2.Text = "";
        // 
        // richTextBox3
        // 
        this.richTextBox3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.richTextBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 286);
        this.richTextBox3.Name = "richTextBox3";
        this.richTextBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(424, 278);
        this.richTextBox3.TabIndex = 2;
        this.richTextBox3.Text = "";
        // 
        // richTextBox4
        // 
        this.richTextBox4.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.richTextBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(433, 286);
        this.richTextBox4.Name = "richTextBox4";
        this.richTextBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(425, 278);
        this.richTextBox4.TabIndex = 3;
        this.richTextBox4.Text = "";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(12F, 25F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(922, 659);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```