# Allow user to change textbox size during runtime

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

Quick question. Is it possible in a windows form to allow the user to resize a textbox while the application is running? I have seen a couple sample codes that have `Dim rc as ResizeableControl` etc etc. Is there a simple way to do this? I already have multiline turned on for it but I want to the user to be able to alter the size of it since I will be populating the textbox with sql queries. I want the user to be able to drag the size of the textbox, not just enlarge the overall window and the textbox grow with it. The answer someone said this is a duplicate of does not allow a user to increase the size or the textbox without increasing the size of the window.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The stuff I was looking up was all vb not c# so no I have not unfortunately. Just seeing if someone could point me in the right direction. I suppose if you want to consider me messing around with the controls such as multiline and locked turned false or true then yea I have tried that.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22283371/2263683)

Comment: @AlexJolig that is basically just the anchoring. That doesn't allow the user to change it independently to the size of that actual window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17264543/17034

Comment: @HansPassant I sent you an email. It isn't liking when I put that in. If you could directly message me or reply back that would be greatly appreciated. For some reason I need a reputation of 50 to comment on the other question that you linked.

Answer (score 0):

In your `[Design]` on `Properties` under `Design`, set the `Locked` property to `False` so that you can resize the textbox control as long as Multiline is also set to `True`

Comment: I have that but that doesn't allow you to resize it while the application is running. For example, the box I am currently writing in allows me to resize it as I am typing. That is what I want to do.